# Unable to create user with systemd-homed

Tags: systemd

I am trying to create a new user with systemd-homed, but I receive an error

```
# homectl create jjcasmar
Please enter new password for user jjcasmar: *           
Please enter new password for user jjcasmar (repeat): *        
Operation on home jjcasmar failed: Failed to execute operation: Protocol error
```

systemd-homed logs show the following

```
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homed[865]: jjcasmar: changing state absent → creating
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Using automatic default storage of 'luks'.
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Sizing home to 83% of available disk space, which is 254.0G.
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Allocating image file completed.
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Writing of partition table completed.
Sep 11 11:41:39 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Setting up loopback device /dev/loop2 completed.
Sep 11 11:41:41 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: LUKS formatting completed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Writing password to LUKS keyslot 0 completed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: LUKS activation by volume key succeeded.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Writing user record as LUKS token completed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: Setting up LUKS device /dev/mapper/home-jjcasmar completed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homed[5423]: mkfs.btrfs: error while loading shared libraries: cannot make segment writable for relocation: Permission denied
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homework[5413]: (mkfs) failed with exit status 127.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homed[865]: block device /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-1 has been removed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homed[865]: block device /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-1 has been removed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homed[865]: block device /sys/devices/virtual/block/loop2 has been removed.
Sep 11 11:41:42 mongol systemd-homed[865]: Operation on jjcasmar failed: Protocol error
```

The /home partition is a btrfs subvolume, and I can write into it without problems.
I am using archlinux, just updated

I am out of ideas of what is wrong here. What is wrong here?

Comment: Just to update anyone else reading this, there appears to be some thoughts on the causes of this in the related bug reports that were also submitted: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/29160 and https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/79654

Comment: I will actually close the issue here, since appears to be a bug upstream, possibly in Archlinux, and its already being checked